# DirectAdmin FTP for all domains

Tags: ftp, admin, directadmin

I was searching for an option to show all
domains with your FTP client using DirectAdmin.

So I can make a user called user for example, it will make the domain user.nl
But I'm getting tired of searching the passwords for the FTP accounts day after day, so is their te possibility to do this with the admin account to get a level higher in the FTP?

So I have a structured view of all domains?

Comment: maybe this would be better suited for serverfault.com?